# How to draw single axis plot using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I want to draw a graph which presents 1,000 idioms along a single axis (the axis ranges from 1-5. The axis labels are the idioms. E.g.

raining cats and dogs........make an excuse................raise a question

|---------------------------------|------------------------------|
1....................................................3................................................5

I encounter four problems:

1. How do I draw this graph using ggplot2
2. How do I dodge the axis labels (because they are too long, 4-10 words each)
3. The axis ends up too long (1,000 idioms)
4. How do I 'jitter' the points to avoid overcrowding

I found a related solution proposed in [How to plot a single value on an axis in ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54727721/how-to-plot-a-single-value-on-an-axis-in-ggplot2) using R base's plot function. But it doesn't solve all my problems. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
idioms <- data.frame(rating = runif(1000, 1, 5))

ggplot(idioms, aes(rating, 0)) +
  geom_jitter() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1,3,5),
                     labels = c("raining cats and dogs",
                                "\nmake an excuse", # manual vertical dodge
                                "raise a question")) +
  # this is all just aesthetics
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(hjust = c(0,0.5,1)))
```

[image]